# Inverse Fourier Transform of δ(t) but octave computes it wrong

Tags: fft, octave

I want to inverse fourier transform of Dirac Delta function, δ(t).
So i do these:

```
>> syms F w t
>> F(w)=dirac(w)
F(w) = (symfun) DiracDelta(w)
>> ifourier(F(w))
ans = (sym)

   1
  ----
  2*pi
```

Although the right result should be like this:

[image: the right result]

Any explanation why does it compute wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different conventions for the fourier transform [This](https://www.wtamu.edu/~dcraig/PHYS4340/070413_FTconventions.pdf) page  describes some of the common ones, see also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Other_conventions)

The convention octave is using for the Fourier transform is the standard one. In this convention the fourier transform has no constant factor in front of the integral, so requires a factor of 1 / 2π in front of the inverse (so that F ⚬ f = Id).

There are several reasons to prefer the convention you are using where the standard definition is multiplied by a constant of 1 / √2π. It's more symmetric because the inverse  will have the same constant factor out the front. It also "normalizes" the fourier transform which is useful in certain contexts. But it's not the convention octave is using.